# Order of pole $\frac{\sin^3(z-1)}{\log^4(z)[1-\cos(z-1)]^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the order of pole at $z_0=1$

$$\frac{\sin^3(z-1)}{\log^4(z)[1-\cos(z-1)]^2}$$

I have two options?

Write the Laurent series or using derivatives, all seems very tiresome, and I am may missing something is there another way?

Comment: Using Laurent expansion isn't tiresome al all. But isn't it obvious that the order of the pole is $5$?

Comment: $log^4(z)$ is order $4$ but how can I infer on $(1-cos(z-1))^2$? can I use derivative

Comment: $1-\cos w$ has a double zero at $w=0$.

Comment: I agree it is obvious that the order is 5

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Note that for $w=z-1$ then
$$\frac{\sin^3(z-1)}{\log^4(z)[1-\cos(z-1)]^2}=\frac{\sin^3(w)}{\log^4(1+w)[1-\cos(w)]^2}$$
Now use the Taylor expansions of $\sin(w)$, $\log(1+w)$, $\cos(w)$ at $0$. In particular recall that $\cos(w)=1-\frac{w^2}{2}+ o(w^2).$

Comment: @Bernard I think I have already edit that.

Comment: But I need to take $cos$ to the power of $2$ so it order of $4$?

Comment: Yes! $(1-\cos(w))^2=(\frac{w^2}{2}+ o(w^2))^2=w^4/4+o(w^4)$

Answer (score 0):

Let $u=z-1$ therefore$$\frac{\sin^3(z-1)}{\log^4(z)[1-\cos(z-1)]^2}=\frac{\sin^3(u)}{\log^4(1+u)[1-\cos(u)]^2}=\dfrac{2\sin\dfrac{u}{2}\cos^3\dfrac{u}{2}}{\log^4(1+u)}$$then the pole is of order $3$ since the zeros of $\log^4(1+u)$ and $\sin\dfrac{u}{2}$ are of order $4$ and $1$ respectively.

Comment: As the pole has order $5$, then something has gone wrong ... possibly your trig function calculations.